# TListView.Clear freezes my application,how do i fix it?

Tags: delphi, freeze, delphi-2009

I have a ListView:TListview on my form ,and, I add many values(approximately 25k TListViewItem) ,which works quite fast,but when I call Listview.Clear,the program freezes.I checked it with debugger,it won't step that line.

My question is: how do I solve my problem? If creating so many items in less than a second is possible,why deleting them takes forever(I waited over 5 minutes)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried enclosing your call to **Clear** in a BeginUpdate/EndUpdate block:

```
  listview.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    listview.Items.Clear;
  finally
    listview.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
```

Adding/Removing items in a listview (or various other controls, e.g. listbox) triggers a GUI update of the control for each and every item that is added/removed.  For a listview in particular, this can be quite expensive and for 25,000 items the overhead would be significant.

Admittedly 5 minutes does sound excessive, but this would be the first thing I would try.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing I'd try is wrap your call to Clear with BeginUpdate/EndUpdate.

```
  ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  ListView1.Clear;
  ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
```

Do you have any events attached to the ListView, and are they firing as the list is being cleared?

Comment: That time is being spent somewhere.  Are any events firing? I'd use breakpoints or CodeSite/OutputDebugString messages to see. I like CodeSite for this because it has an IDE plug-in to put EnterMethod/ExitMethod messages in all (or a selection of) your methods in a unit.

Answer (score 2):

as the others noted a BeginUpdate .... EndUpdate will greatly increase performance, however I would really suggest you move your code to use VirtualTreeView. It's a hybrit tree/ListView which will add up to 1m nodes in less than a second (actually that depends on the processor, but you get the idea).

It's a bit harder to learn in the beginning but once you get used to it you'll find it "easy" to work with. I personally whenever I need many rows in a ListView or TreeView look no further than VirtualTreeView. Oh, and forgot to mention that on top of it, it's free. Try it from : http://soft-gems.net/

Answer (score 2):

John, it should not be longer to clear than to add the 25k items.
I wonder if you load it while it is not visible (automatically disabling updates), but clear it when it is visible where each item deletion triggers an update.

Comment: It's visible.BeginUpdate/EndUpdate is user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I should delete this question or not,I believe it's not going to be in any use to anyone else,but I prefer to keep it for awhile at least for you,who answered.

The problem was that I used a component inheriting from TListView,I thought It wouldn't be a problem so I decided to say TListView,but I was wrong.

I upvoted all your answers, please excuse my ignorance - I'm new.

Comment: Don't sweat it.  So, what is the component you're using?  Something home grown, or from a third party?

Comment: AlphaControls,it's awhole skin package with controls inheriting from borland's vcl and their skinView(TsSkinView) is quite bad.

Comment: What was the problem exactly? Was their clear code so slow? Why was it?

Comment: No,it just freezes if you call Listbox.clean and there are many items on the listbox.

Comment: Maybe dereferencing a nil pointer? That causes most of the freezes for me.

Comment: It is a good question, even generally in GUI, so maybe you should delete only "this answer" ?